Midrash about our "age" in Olam Haba
I once heard that there is a midrash that states in Olam Haba, we start each day as children, then the next quarter we are adolescent, then adult, then old age, so that we can enjoy the goodness of each of those stages of life.
Does anyone know the source of this?
Note: I heard this a long time ago, and I have a vague memory that this might have turned out to be from an untrustworthy source, so apologies if so. I also have a vague memory that I ended up finding it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ and if so I am curious to learn it inside.

Which olam habbah are you referring to?

I have provided all the information I have on the matter

Because according to the Rambam's understanding of olam Habbah as the world of souls, it doesn't seem like any bodily things would apply

I am happy if the answerer holds like the Rambam about midrashim

There are different levels of olam Habbah though. Even nowadays there is the world of souls according to all, while in other contexts the world to come refers to after the time of the resurrection. I guess the question would be at what stage in life would they be resurrected at, if so?

Maybe we can figure that out by looking at the source inside, if it exists
